# Csvhelper writer datasourcs

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am using csvhelper to import certain fields in a datagridview with no issues and then I have other columns added that has user imputed data. That part works.
Now when I try to write the datagridview to a new csv file and I get no data just headers that I have from the class. So where am I going wrong?

My write to code:

```
private void SchedSaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var records = new List<WriteCsvschedule>
    {             
        new WriteCsvschedule { EmpName = "1", EmpPayrollID = "2" },
    };

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\rcs\export\sched.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }            
}
```

and my class:

```
public class WriteCsvschedule
{
    [Index(0)]
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    [Index(1)]
    public string EmpPayrollID { get; set; }
    [Index(2)]
    public string JobName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your missing some code or something, your code works for me as expected: `EmpName,EmpPayrollID,JobName
1,2,`

Comment: but that is what it is pulling in from with in the code. I need to be able to pull the data that is in the datagridview to the csv

Comment: Have you tried using the same datasource as your dgv?

Comment: my first 3 columns comes from a data source the rest are the dgv. and I am not sure how I would use the datasource for it